# Simplify basic math expression

Tags: education

The task is so simplify the following expression.

[image: Simplify the expression]

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Try to do it, the answer is $\frac{1}{x^{2}y^{2}}$

Comment: I was kinda close to get a good result, but I fell into a trap of expanding all of these powers at one point. Thank you for your courage <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying:

$\frac{1}{(x + y)^{2}}\big(\frac{1}{x^{2}} + \frac{1}{y^{2}}\big) + \frac{2}{(x + y)^{3}}\big(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}\big)$,

$\frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}\frac{x^{2} + y^{2}}{x^{2}y^{2}} + \frac{2}{(x+y)^{3}}\frac{x + y}{xy}$,

$\frac{1}{(x + y)^{2}}\frac{x^{2} + y^{2}}{x^{2}y^{2}} + \frac{2}{(x +y)^{2}xy}$,

$\frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}\big(\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{x^{2}y^{2}} + \frac{2xy}{x^{2}y^{2}}\big)$,

$\frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}\frac{(x +y)^{2}}{x^{2}y^{2}}$,

$\boxed{\frac{1}{x^{2}y^{2}}.}$

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck on it for two hours

Comment: When you see a sum of fractions like that, the best thing you can do is get a common denominator.

Comment: Yess! I wasn't far from the good track i think, i just got lost at one point and tried to expand all of these powers :c But im good now, I've found my mistakes!